# How to update data in a joined table from a default view? - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller

I am a beginner Ruby on Rails student, trying to fix up this mess I found myself in :D I'm trying to build a web app that allows registered users to buy bus tickets, while unregistered users can only browse through the ticket list. There are 3 tables ***User*** (created with devise), ***Ticket***(a table that contains tickets...I seeded sample data inside) and ***Bought*** (joined table from User and Ticket since the link is many-to-many. Database schema is the following :

```
  create_table "boughts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "user_id", null: false
    t.integer "ticket_id", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.index ["ticket_id"], name: "index_boughts_on_ticket_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_boughts_on_user_id"
  end

  create_table "tickets", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "bus"
    t.datetime "time"
    t.integer "quantity"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.integer "price"
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "email", default: "", null: false
    t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
    t.string "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
  end

  add_foreign_key "boughts", "tickets"
  add_foreign_key "boughts", "users"
end
```

Now, when a registered/logged-in user clicks "Buy" button (its a fake buy), I want to insert a row into table "Boughts" with this particular user's ID, and with the ID of the ticket he clicked "Buy" next to. The purpose of this is that this user can later view the tickets he has bought on his "bought tickets view", or something of the sort.

***Index/Home view (pages.html.erb)***

```
    <%= link_to 'Sign out',destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete %>

    <table>
    <thead> 
        <tr>
            <td>Bus</td>
            <td>Time</td>
            <td>Quantity</td>
            <td>Price</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <% @tickets.each do |ticket| %>
        <tr>
            <td><%= ticket.bus %></td>
            <td><%= ticket.time %></td>
            <td><%= ticket.quantity %></td>
            <td><%= ticket.price %></td>
            <td>
                <%= button_to 'Buy', create_path, method: :post %>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <% end %>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

***Pages controller***

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def home
    @tickets = Ticket.all

  end
  def create
    @boughts = Bought.new(bought_params)

        if bought.save
            redirect_to :root
        else
            flash[:errors] = bought.errors.full_messages
            redirect_back fallback_location: root_path
        end
  end
  private
    def bought_params
        params.require(:bought).permit(:user_id, :ticket_id)
    end
end
```

***Routes***

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :tickets
  resources :boughts
  devise_for :users
  root to: "pages#home"
  post '/create', to: 'pages#create', as: 'create'
end
```

Should I update the boughts table from a "boughts" controller, or can I do it from the pages_controller (the controller for the main view/index homepage). This specific code doesn't work, the error is ("param is missing or the value is empty: bought"). The goal is to fill the boughts table with user-bought tickets and then display them on that users's specific profile page.

Answer (score 1):

You're correct in thinking this isn't entirely best practice.

You should be submitting directly to the `boughts_controller` because that's the only thing you're trying to create/update from this single button click.

The other problem is you're not sending any parameters to the `create` method.

Assuming you generated the `boughts_controller` with a scaffold command

```
<%= button_to 'Buy', boughts_path(bought: {user_id: current_user.id, ticket_id: ticket }) %>
```

`method: :post` is not needed, this is the default for `button_to`, you can see the documentation on this here: https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/button_to

Then from the `boughts_controller`, after the "tracking" record is created, you should redirect to the path where the user can actually buy something.

Comment: Thanks scilence. I will try to implement your solution as soon as possible. I will post the results here. :D :D